# AppBarLayout doesn't respect scrolling of its sibling's children

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm currently trying to have a recycler view inside of a fragment affect the applications Toolbar, which is wrapped by a AppBarLayout (for the fun scrolling stuff).

I've look everywhere online, and no one has come up with a direct answer. The only answers I've seen are ones that say to just put the layout_behavior scrolling tag on the frameLayout which the fragment will go in. The only thing here is that the AppbarLayout only respects the "scrolling" of the FrameLayout, and not that of the RecyclerView which is a child of the FrameLayout.

I'm currently dealing with the following view hierarchy.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout/>
    <FrameLayout> (Container for Fragment)
        <LinearLayout>
            <RecyclerView/>
        <LinearLayout/>
    </FrameLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Has anyone been able to overcome this and figure it out?

The Notable Problem is that I can't use the enterAlways scroll feature, which anyone would want in a scrollable app.